# How can I establish whether it would be a good idea to upgrade from Express to Standard?

Tags: sql-server-2017

In Express 2019 running on Linux, If I right click my database I can see that it is size 11506 Mb with 1963 Mb free space. Currently showing 17 users.

I am trying to work out whether it would be better to delete records or upgrade.

Given the cost to upgrade is significant, how can I establish what performance benefits we might gain?

If we trial upgradeing can we roll back?

Comment: I learned that Express does not support a dedicated admin connection , handy for troubleshooting  spids

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing considerations are off-topic here.

Comment: It is a technical question about editions. Maybe I could phrase the question better?

Comment: Definitely: you have multiple questions, all driven by the fact that Microsoft has chosen to license their product in a certain way. Suggest you ask separate questions. Re performance benefits: I wouldn’t expect night-and-day difference in basic functionality. Reverting back to the free edition can surely always be achieved with export and import, but requires down time. Deleting data or implementing processes to do so also costs time/money. Given effort is required and you’re already running Linux, is migrating to Postgres an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to work out whether it would be better to delete records or upgrade.

**This is a business decision**, not a technical one. Do not just delete data "to make space" - if the data is important and must be retained, then the organization will have to find a way to pay to keep it around.

You can't downgrade SQL Server in the way you're suggesting.

If you want to explore the possibility of upgrading to a paid edition of SQL Server, I suggest setting up a new server with Developer Edition installed (Developer Edition is free). Then take a backup of your current database, restore it to this test server, and run a sample of your workload against that.

If you decide you need to upgrade to Standard Edition, this method (backup & restore) is also how you'll move your data over. I do not recommend performing an in-place upgrade (which is what your proposed method suggests).

If you're currently satisfied with the overall performance of your setup, and only looking into upgrading due to the database size limitations of Express Edition, you have a few options:

1. Create a second database which mirrors the first, splitting the data between the two. This will require application changes
2. Move "old" data to a second (archival) database based on age, deleting it from the original database
3. Just delete the old data altogether
4. Implement page- or row-level compression on your tables & indexes to buy some more time. But eventually, you'll hit the 10GB limit anyway.
5. Migrate to a cloud-hosted database platform like Azure SQL DB where you'll pay for what you use

Options 2 & 3 should only be considered if the business requirements for the data allow for it. Option 5 should only be considered if the business's data governance policies allow for it.

Comment: I've got these and a few other strategies for reducing express DB sizes on my site: https://expressdb.io/sql-server-express-database-size-limit.html if you decide to take this route @kirsten

Comment: Thanks @alroc I asked a related question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260470/does-express-store-any-statistics-to-indicate-when-performance-is-held-up-due-to